# Error in showing tabs in android

Tags: android, listview, tabs

I am working on Tabs with each tab showing a List view

My Code is as follows: (I am showing the code for only the first Tab)
can anyone please help where am I going wrong?

MY XML file is as follows

```
<TabWidget
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="60dp" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/pcards_list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

and my MAIN.XML is as follows

IT shows no errors but still the program crashes when i run it on my emulator

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        TabHost mtabhost =(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        mtabhost.setup();

        TabSpec spec1 = mtabhost.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
        spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        spec1.setIndicator("Personal Cards");

        ListView  pcards_list= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.pcards_list);
        ArrayList<String> pcards_arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();



        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1= new  ArrayAdapter<String(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,pcards_arraylist);
        pcards_list.setAdapter(adapter1);

        mtabhost.addTab(spec1);

    }
}
```

please help me out!

and can any one provide me a good tutorial on tabs and also tabs using fragments having listview ??
thankyou in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***main.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/myList"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
                </ListView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

***AndroidTabActivity.java***

```
public class AndroidTabActivity extends TabActivity {

    ListView mList;

    String[] myContacts = { "Anirudh", "Sonia", "Raj", "Sachin" };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);

        ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myContacts);

        mList.setAdapter(myAdapter);


        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        // Tab for Contact
        TabSpec contactspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Contact");
        // setting Title for the Tab
        contactspec.setIndicator("Contact");
        contactspec.setContent(R.id.tab1);

        // Tab for Song
        TabSpec songspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Song");
        songspec.setIndicator("Songs");
        Intent songIntent = new Intent(this, SongActivity.class);
        songspec.setContent(songIntent);


        // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
        tabHost.addTab(contactspec); // Adding contact tab
        tabHost.addTab(songspec); // Adding song tab

    }
}
```

[image: Output]

In this way you can create tabs and set the appropriate `Activity` as content.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good tutorial: http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/
Also check: http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/

Answer (score 1):

i learned doing the Tabs within the Tutorial from Travis (84 - 86).
Not sure if it really helps, while you didnt do the rest of it before.

http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=6&number=84

Answer (score 0):

Do u have given permission for that `Activity` in `AndroidManifest.xml`??? If not, add the permission under `application` tag as below:

```
 <activity android:name="MainActivity"/>
```